# Laravel create related Model view, pass prefilled value

Tags: laravel, view, relation

i am implementing a backoffice system with many Models and Relations.

Now im stuck with my UI Stragegy:
Lets assume i have Houses and Rooms. One House has many Rooms.

I have created controllers for both Models the "Laravel" way.(Resource Controllers)

So i have routes for both of them

example.com/backoffice/house

example.com/backoffice/room

What i want to implement sounds simple:

I want an Button inside the Detail View of a House ("Create Room for this House") which redirects me to "room/create" but in the create view i want to set the value for "house_id" to the id of the House i am comming from. So i can normaly use the store method in the RoomController and then redirect back to the house.

I want a general way because i must use this function on many Models/Views. I am thinking about a session variable but i think eventually has someone a better way for generally handling such cases? Or a better idea for UI Handling?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Laravel removed some of their awesome documentation for version 5.6, being `nested resource controllers`.

What you could do, is use nested routes.

Let's assume your current controllers are set up the following way:

```
Route::resource('houses', 'HouseController');
Route::resource('rooms', 'RoomController');
```

If you change this part to the following:

```
Route::resource('houses', 'HouseController');
Route::resource('houses.rooms', 'RoomController');
```

This couples every room to a house and is really easy to manage. It gives you URL's like `houses/4/rooms/create`, which gives you a `house_id` in your create method instantly:

```
public function create($houseId)
{
    return view('houses.rooms.create', ['houseId' => $houseId]);
}
```

If you want to edit a room, it is exactly the same:

```
public function edit($houseId, $roomId)
```

The [Laravel 5.1 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources) still has an example of this technique.

Comment: Wow, that seems a good idea. But what if i want to manage all rooms so that the user kann select rooms from the index view, and edit it without going over a house?

I think defining two or mor ressource routes for one Model is acceptable if i can use the same controller.
Route::resource('houses.rooms', 'RoomController');
Route::resource('rooms', 'RoomController');

public function create($houseId = null)
{
    return view('rooms.create', ['houseId' => $houseId]);
}

I think i will try that.

Comment: Kinda depends on how you have structured your whole application, but you could have an extra route for all the rooms Route::get(‘manage_rooms’, ‘RoomController@allRooms’).

Answer (score 1):

To do this, i would suggest the following way (there might be other ways also)

**Change Route:**

```
Route::get('room/create/{house_id?},'Controller@action')->name('room.create')
```

**Add `<a>` tag in `house_view.blade.php` file.**

```
<a href="{{route('room.create', ['house_id' => $houseModel->id])}}">Create Room for this House</a>
```

**Room Controller file.**

```
public function formCreate($house_id)
 {
   return view('form.room_create', ['house_id' => $house_id]);
 }
```

**Add type hidden `<input>` tag in `room_create.blade.php` file**

```
<input type="hidden" id="house_id" name="house_id" value="{{$house_id or ''}}">
```

Comment: Downvoted because of formatting. Fix that, mention me and I'll remove it.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan check now. ;-)

Comment: Almost ;) I just edited the titles a little bit more, so they aren't as big as they used to!

Comment: Thanks @DouwedeHaan, will correct my self. New to posting.. :)